# Как правильно написать?

Tags: грамматика

Столкнулась с трудностью написания названия отдела: сметно-договорной или сметно-договорный? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще орфоэпическими словарями рекомендуется форма "договорный" как основная во всех значениях. 
Договорной - как допустимая.
Но боюсь, что "договорной" настолько вошло в практику, что спорить бесполезно. Тем более, что и словарный запрет на неё не абсолютный.

Comment: Например, договорнЫе цены - с 1991 года, и договОрными никогда не были.

Comment: Кстати да. Но это может быть от разницы в значениях, о чем говорит Виктор. Но не уверен.Возможно, просто профжаргон.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что "договорный" - 
это значит основанный на договоре, связанный с договором, а "договорной" - занимающийся договорами. Сметно-договорной отдел - это отдел, занимающийся вопросами смет и договоров.

Answer (score 0):

**ДОГОВОРНЫЙ**.

В словаре Т.Ф.Ивановой "***Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка***" 2008 это слово стоит даже с пометой (**!**).

Comment: А что это за помета - !-?

Comment: Это знак, указывающий "на строгую нормативность и обязательность того или иного ударения или произношения". (Цитата из того же словаря, статья "Нормативные и пояснительные пометы".)